# What's the difference between Try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu option in VirtualBox?

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, windows, multiple-instances, selenium

What is the difference between "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu" option?

I have VirtualBox on my Windows 10 and have downloaded Ubuntu ISO on my desktop.

I have configured the VirtualBox and provide Ubuntu ISO for Virtualbox. I get two options - "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu". I am not sure which option to take.

My requirement is I want to run my Selenium scripts in parallel for which I need multiple machines, hence using VM.

If I select Install Ubuntu will it alter my laptop's file system? I intend to use VM temporarily to learn the concept of parallel script execution across multiple machines. Post learning I want to remove VirtualBox and don't want Ubuntu.

Comment: Try Ubuntu is like going to a store and trying on a pair of jeans. Installing Ubuntu is like buying the same pair of jeans and taking them home and wearing them.

Comment: If you are running the .iso in VirtualBox, then it will alter the *virtual* disk, leaving your Windows 10 OS untouched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try Ubuntu** will run live image of Ubuntu system, this will not actually installing Ubuntu—thus changes you made here not gonna be saved and will be gone after shutdown.

**Install Ubuntu** probably is the one you want, it will install full Ubuntu within Virtualbox sandbox, storing all the changes on virtual hard disk (usually `.vdi` file).

Installing Ubuntu on Virtualbox will not affect your main filesystem—except for hard disk space usage I assume you already figure that out.